# Recurrence relation for Catalan numbers

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, combinations, catalan-numbers

While trying to find the number of distinct ways we can multiply (parenthesize) n matrices without changing their order ([Matrix Chain Multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication)) and using a bottom up approach, I came up with this recurrence relation for Catalan Numbers -

$$T(n) = \binom{n-1}{1}.T(n-1) - \binom{n-2}{2}.T(n-2)   +  \binom{n-3}{3}.T(n-3) - \binom{n-4}{4}.T(n-4)...$$

or
$$\bbox[5px] T(n) = \lvert \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} (-1)^{n-k}.\binom{n-k}{k}.T(n-k) \rvert$$

Where T(n) is the nth Catalan Number.

From the Top Down approach and from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) we get the solution -

$$C_{n}={\frac {1}{n+1}}{2n \choose n}={\frac {(2n)!}{(n+1)!\,n!}}=\prod \limits _{k=2}^{n}{\frac {n+k}{k}}\qquad {\mbox{ for }}n\geq 0.$$

Is it possible to derive one from the other?

For any given set- $$ABCDE$$

Bottom Up approach: Make pairs of 2 matrices and remove the duplicate solutions - 
$$(AB)CDE,\bbox[5px] A(BC)DE, \bbox[5px]AB(CD)E, \bbox[5px]ABC(DE)$$

Top Down approach: Seperate the set into two distinct sets, no need to remove duplicates - 
$$(A)(BCDE), \bbox[5px](AB)(CDE), \bbox[5px](ABC)(DE), \bbox[5px](ABCD)(E)$$

Comment: It would be nice to replace $\phantom{}^a C_b$ with $\binom{a}{b}$ ($\text{\binom{a,b}}$) and $.$ with $\cdot$ ($\text{\cdot}$).

Comment: I'm new here, so didn't know if $\binom{a}{b}$ was permutation or combination. Will change

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191524/a-recurrence-relation-on-catalan-numbers for the correct formula.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/q/391980/11260 (note the +1 on the right-hand-side, you need that)

Answer (score 3):

We  clear up  some ambiguities  in  the post  and prove  it by  strong
induction. We let $T(0)=0$ and $T(1)=1$ and prove that when

$$T(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
(-1)^{k+1} {n-k\choose k} T(n-k)$$

for $n\ge 2$ then $$T(n) = C_{n-1} 
= \frac{1}{n} {2n-2\choose n-1}
= {2n-2\choose n-1} - {2n-2\choose n}.$$

In fact the case of a zero argument to $T$ is not reached as for $n\ge
2$ we also  have $n-\lfloor n/2\rfloor \ge 1.$  Applying the induction
hypothesis on the RHS we get two pieces, the first is

$$A = \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
(-1)^{k+1} {n-k\choose k} {2n-2k-2\choose n-k-1}
\\ = {2n-2\choose n-1} +
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
(-1)^{k+1} {n-k\choose k} {2n-2k-2\choose n-k-1}
$$

and the second

$$B = \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
(-1)^{k+1} {n-k\choose k} {2n-2k-2\choose n-k}
\\ = {2n-2\choose n} +
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
(-1)^{k+1} {n-k\choose k} {2n-2k-2\choose n-k}.$$

As we subtract $B$ from $A$ we see  that we only need to show that the
contribution from the two sum terms call them $A'$ and $B'$ is zero.

For these two pieces we introduce the integral representation

$${n-k\choose k} = {n-k\choose n-2k} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n-2k+1}} (1+z)^{n-k} \; dz.$$

This  has  the nice  property  that  it  vanishes when  $k\gt  \lfloor
n/2\rfloor$ so we may extend the upper limit of the sum to infinity.
We also introduce for the first sum

$${2n-2k-2\choose n-k-1} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n-k}} (1+w)^{2n-2k-2} \; dw.$$

We thus obtain

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n}} (1+w)^{2n-2} 
\\ \times \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} (1+z)^{n}
\sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{z^{2k} w^k}{(1+z)^k (1+w)^{2k}} 
\; dz\; dw
\\ = - \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n}} (1+w)^{2n-2} 
\\ \times \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} (1+z)^{n}
\frac{1}{1+z^2 w/(1+z)/(1+w)^2}
\; dz\; dw
\\ = -\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n}} (1+w)^{2n} 
\\ \times \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} (1+z)^{n+1}
\frac{1}{(1+z)(1+w)^2+z^2 w}
\; dz\; dw
\\ = -\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} (1+w)^{2n} 
\\ \times \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} (1+z)^{n+1}
\frac{1}{z+1+w} \frac{1}{z + (1+w)/w}
\; dz\; dw.$$

We evaluate the  inner integral by summing the  residues at $z=-(1+w)$
and  $z=-(1+w)/w$ and  flipping the  sign.  (We will  verify that  the
residue at infinity is zero.)

The residue at $z=-(1+w)$ yields

$$-\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} (1+w)^{2n} 
\\ \times \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(1+w)^{n+1}} (-1)^{n+1} w^{n+1} 
\frac{1}{-(1+w)+(1+w)/w} \; dw
\\ = -\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}  (1+w)^{n-1} \frac{w}{1-w^2}\; dw.$$

This is zero as the pole at zero has been canceled. Next for the residue
at $z=-(1+w)/w$ we get

$$-\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} (1+w)^{2n} 
\\ \times \frac{(-1)^{n+1} w^{n+1}}{(1+w)^{n+1}}
(-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} \frac{1}{-(1+w)/w+1+w} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} (1+w)^{n-1} 
\frac{w}{1-w^2} dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n}} (1+w)^{n-2} 
\frac{1}{1-w} dw.$$

With $n\ge 2$ we can evaluate this as
$$\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n-2\choose q} = 2^{n-2}.$$

To wrap up the residue at infinity of the inner integral is

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\infty} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} (1+z)^{n+1}
\frac{1}{z+1+w} \frac{1}{z + (1+w)/w}
\\ = -\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^2} z^{n+1} 
\frac{(1+z)^{n+1}}{z^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{1/z+1+w} \frac{1}{1/z + (1+w)/w}
\\ = -\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} (1+z)^{n+1}
\frac{1}{1 + z (1+w)} \frac{1}{1 + z (1+w)/w} = 0.$$

Collecting everything and flipping the sign we have shown that

$$A' = - 2^{n-2}.$$

For piece $B'$ we  see that it only differs from $A'$  in an extra $1/w$
factor on the extractor in $w$ at the front. We thus obtain

$$-\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n+2}} (1+w)^{2n}
\\ \times \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} (1+z)^{n+1}
\frac{1}{z+1+w} \frac{1}{z + (1+w)/w}
\; dz\; dw.$$

The residue at $z=-(1+w)$ vanishes the same because there was an extra
$w$ to spare on the $w/(1-w^2)$ term:

$$-\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}  (1+w)^{n-1} \frac{1}{1-w^2}\; dw.$$

For the residue at $z=-(1+w)/w$ we are now extracting from

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} (1+w)^{n-2}
\frac{1}{1-w} dw.$$

to get

$$\sum_{q=0}^{n} {n-2\choose q} = 2^{n-2}$$

as before. The  residue at infinity vanished in $z$  and did not reach
the front  extractor in  $w$, for another  contribution of  zero. This
means that

$$B' = - 2^{n-2}$$

and we  may conclude the  proof. The fact that  the sum term  from the
geometric series factored as it did  is the remarkable feature of this
problem.

**Addendum, four  years  later.** In  the  present version  with
complex variables the proof requires  the convergence of the geometric
series.   This is  $|z^2 w  /(1+z)/(1+w)^2 |  \lt 1$  or $|z^2  w| \lt
|(1+z)  (1+w)^2|.$  Now  we  have $|(1+z)  (1+w)^2|  \ge  (1-\epsilon)
(1-\gamma)^2$  so $(1-\epsilon)  (1-\gamma)^2  \gt \epsilon^2  \gamma$
will do. Suppose we take  $\epsilon = \gamma.$ We obtain $(1-\gamma)^3
\gt  \gamma^3.$ Therefore  e.g.   $\epsilon =  \gamma  = 1/4$  ensures
convergence of  the series. This  also ensures  that the two  poles at
$-(1+w)$ and $-(1+w)/w$ are outside the contour $|z|=\epsilon.$

Comment: Nice work! (+1)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have added some details concerning piece B as I wrote the first draft in a hurry.

Answer (score 1):

If $T(n)$ fulfills
$$ T(n) = \sum_{k\geq 1}\binom{n-k}{k}(-1)^{k+1} T(n-k) $$
then $T(n)$ is related with a [Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials):

$$ U_n(x) = \sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{n-k}{k}(-1)^k (2x)^{n-2k} $$
and from the generating function for $\{U_n(x)\}_{n\geq 0}$
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}U_n(x)\,z^n = \frac{1}{1-2x z+z^2} $$
we may find the generating function $\sum_{n\geq 0}T(n)\,z^n=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}$ and deduce
$$ C_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n} $$
from the extended binomial theorem. That is kind of unusual but it works.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "related"?